# Admin button "send shipment notification" not responding

Tags: adminhtml, javascript

In admin panel, in shipment detail view, the button "send shipment notification" has no effect. (no error, no log, no action at all).

In the page html it is defined as:

```
<button style="" onclick="deleteConfirm('Voulez-vous vraiment envoyer l'e-mail d'expédition au client ?', 'http://www.mysite.fr/index.php/admin/sales_order_shipment/email/shipment_id/1/key/942e4be724b96b93bfd660ef3ded72bd/')" class="scalable save" type="button" title="Envoyer une information de suivi" id="id_61c746468dcf6ec337ab6f70d3e0640d"><span><span><span>Envoyer une information de suivi</span></span></span></button>
```

the deleteConfirm function called by the buttons apparently defined in js/mage/adminhtml/tools.js  but seems not to be run. (i tried adding in it alert("toto") but nothing happens…)

Thank you for your help,

Comment: Do yo have any extension installed which alters the shipment dialog?

Comment: no… I found the solution.

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution, if it can help :

In fact, because of the French translation, the command of the button is :

```
<button style="" onclick="deleteConfirm('Voulez-vous vraiment envoyer l'e-mail d'expédition au client ?',...</button>
```

As you can see, there is the `'` char dans `"l'e-mail"` (char which is often used in French) which was inducing an error, considered by JS as an "end of string"…

Seriously...